# Why am I getting artifacts around the edge of a mesh I'm texture baking?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I’m trying to bake a high poly branch into a plane. I’m getting these weird artifacts around the edges of the mesh. Why am I getting this? Are there any ways to fix this?

[image]

Comment: hello; ùaybe share your file so that we can test. You could rework the image with an image editor or directly in Blender, with a Clone brush, but it's better to understand where this artifacts come from...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. I set the Margin to 0 px. Blender generates additional pixels for seamless bakes which I didn't need.

[image: Margin Set to 0]

Comment: yes that's it, I've just found out as well  ;)